# cron job allowed commands

Tags: centos, bash, cron

i can use this command in cron job

```
 cat /etc/passwd
```

its send my an email about all users info
how i can see allowed command? like cat !
can i use service httpd restart? ( i test it and i cant)
so whats command i allowed?
can i copy on other users file? with cp command?
how safe /etc/passwd  now?
i use cpanel and im just member of that cpanel not admin

Comment: (1) You are asking too many questions within one question. (2) This is not the appropriate forum since you are not the admin - suggest UNIX SE group, (3) for each question, you are going to have to greatly expand the description and provide a lot more information before anybody might help, (4) have you googled for any of this information you desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commands on which you have permission, can execute with cron. You need to use full path of command and which depends upon the PATH settings.

Example:

`/sbin/service http restart` will work

Comment: so all users can stop apache right?

Comment: @masiharastooyi: No. `/sbin` programs are only allowed for root (usually), and this program wouldn't work from a non-root users crontab. The permission requirements are the same for cron as for normal sessions.

Comment: As I said above, all commands on which user have permission can execute the same using cron also.

Comment: so where can i see whats command i allowed? or what is default permission for normal user? in cpanel?

Comment: Via cPanel, you can't execute, almost, any commands (other wise you need to have root access). `php` is a command which you can execute using cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can use all commands in a cron job, but since usually you don't have a full user environment, it's sometimes necessary to give the full path for a command, e.g. like this:

```
 /sbin/service httpd restart
```

Also, naturally, you have to consider that not all commands make sense to be run in a cron job, e.g. if they require interactive input from the user.